# How to embed a mapbox map without having login access?

Tags: html, mapbox, embed

```
<html>  
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
  
<body style='margin: 0'>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="mapContainer"></div>

<script>    
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': 'YOUR API KEY'
      });
      
       const lat = 22.719568;
       const long = 75.857727;
       var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

      var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        maptypes.vector.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 10,
          center: { lat: lat, lng: long }  
        });
        
    var marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat: lat, lng: long });
        
    map.addObject(marker);
        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> this is my code so far but when i run it the code does not show the map in detail
> i want it to display the original map (this is the link https://map.missionuplink.org/)